# How can I sync new content in Google Drive folder, but keep existing content off disk?

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

I want to sync a folder in Google Drive to my system, but only the folder, so it becomes sort of a drag-drop to my Google Drive.
I want the content to be removed from my local HD when the sync is complete. Does anyone know how to do this?